# Allow comment posting once multiple notification error box is dismissed

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, comments, comment-replies, error-message

When posting a comment with multiple @ style notifications, the error appears letting me know that only one person will be notified (two if the post owner is different than the person specified).

I click it, acknowledging that I am fine with that limitation, and try to submit the comment again, and it rejects it.

I understand this limitation - I'm not asking the system to notify more than one person, I'm addressing them in the comment so that in more involved comment areas it's easy to follow the discussion.

Please allow the user to post the comment after they've acknowledged the limitation and dismissed the box.

Note that I'm not asking for multiple people to be notified, I'm merely asking the system to allow users to post such comments even though the system doesn't perform the notification.

I understand there are workarounds (put a space between the @ and the name, or add a backtick to the comment) but I don't see why the system should present this as a hard limit and reject the comment outright.  A warning is sufficient to alert the user to the limitation, but there's no need to reject the comment altogether.

[image: Single comment notification warning]

Comment: I can see the [meta-tag:status-declined] cannon charging off in the distance, but can you provide an example where this actually clarifies the comment thread? I think in your screenshotted example that the comment is primarily useful only to the person who is notified of it.

Answer (score 2):

Allowing this would lead to broken windows -- people would assume that since they see `@name1 @name2` in comments that multiple comment notifications are part of our system.

They aren't.

Bear in mind this was *specifically added* because people complained "but I can type as many `@usernames` as I want in a comment, clearly it should work!"